# How to generate a dataset dynamically with a parameter in "from" clause of "select"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select * from 
(select 0 as hour 
union select 2  union select 4  union select 6  union select 8 
union select 10 union select 12 union select 14 union select 16 
union select 18 union select 20 union select 22 union select 24) hours
go
```

In the above code, "hours" contains hours which are multiple of 2. I need to write some sql statements like above example, the difference between these statements is that they are multiple of other numbers, such as multiple of 3 or 4. So I want to optimize above sql statement with a parameter, like below pseudo code:

```
#Below code creates "hours" with multiple of 3 from 0 to 24.
parameter = 3
select * from 
(select 0 as hour 
union select parameter  union select 2*parameter  union select 3*parameter
... ... 
union select 24) hours
go
```

But I don't how to write it with sql, could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I believe should be a simple table and a textbook use case for modulus(%). There is no need to use recursive CTE's. I would expect my solution to perform well and it's simple.

```
DECLARE @InputNum INT = 2 /*Sample parameter*/

SELECT hr
FROM (
        /*Values should probably be put into a physical table*/
        VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24)
    ) AS A(hr)
WHERE hr % @InputNum = 0
```

**Returns:**

```
hr
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with hours as (
      select 0 as hh
      union all
      select hh + @param
      from cte
      where hh + @param < 24
     )
select *
from hours;
```

If you like, you can put this into a user-defined table valued function.  Then you could call it as:

```
select . . .
from dbo.Hours(2) h(hh);
```

Note:  `hour` is a [reserved word in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql), so I prefer using `hh` as the name of the column.

Comment: If we are only talking about 24 hours, why not just have a list of 0 to 24 and filter using modulus(%)?

Comment: @Stephan . . . That's a valid approach.  Recursive CTEs are more fun though.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, this would work:

Using a stacked cte ([common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)) for numbers:

```
declare @everyN int = 3;
declare @maxN   int = 24;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, numbers as (
  select n = row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                --cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
)
select n
from numbers
where n <= @maxN
  and n % @everyN = 0;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PHZDZA97504

returns:

```
+----+
| n  |
+----+
|  0 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  9 |
| 12 |
| 15 |
| 18 |
| 21 |
| 24 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of sequence it makes sense to have a so-called "Tally" table in your database. A tally table just contains numbers from 0 to x (e. g. 100'000). Based on that, you can create whatever kind of sequence you need, be it "3 hours" like in your case or date ranges or other number ranges. You would use a tally table like so:

```
select Id * 3
  from dbo.Tally
 where Id * 3 <= 24;
```

or better:

```
select Id * 3
  from dbo.Tally
 where Id <= 8;
```

That's very useful when you need to create a date range between a given start and end date:

```
select dateadd(day, Id, StartDate)
  from dbo.Tally
 where dateadd(day, Id, StartDate) <= EndDate;
```